# Ref keeps returning null

Tags: reactjs, dom, ref

I looked at lots of ref examples, not one is working. Can someone tell me why this ref keeps returning null?

```
class GeneralNav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.showMenuTitle = React.createRef();
    console.log(this.showMenuTitle.current)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <p ref={this.showMenuTitle}>menu</p>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you testing its value ? React will assign a value to it when the component mounts.

Comment: God damn, indeed needed to put my console.log between componentDidMount() ... Thanks a lot sir!